# How to send message from page-script to native app in firefox webextentions?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm making a Native Messaging extension in firefox, I have some question:

1. Background-script (addded by [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background) key) and content-script (added by [content-script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts) key). What's different between them and can I use both of them with 1 JS file? If not, I have to send page-script->content-script->background-script->native-app?
2. Which's the best function I need to use to send message from page-script to native app? I followed [this example](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/page-to-extension-messaging) or tried with [this function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage) but it doesn't work.

Comment: I suggest you read the [Anatomy of a WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension) page (perhaps work through reading the pages linked from there). It has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done.

Comment: Using a single file as both a background script and content script is, generally, a bad idea. Many people who have tried it ended up asking questions about why their extension does not  work. While it is certainly possible, and reasonable in some circumstances (e.g. loading the same library file in both contexts), your primary logic is nearly always different between your background script(s) and content script(s). Sharing the same file for both is bad.

Answer (score 1):

1. Background-script can be considered as long term running, since Firefox started, to Firefox process quit. While content scripts runs in web page context, ends when web page closed. Content scripts can be used to access/modify web page, while background script can't. For detail, see documentation of [background scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background), [content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts).
2. You need [Native Messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging) to send message from extension to native app. In extension, use `chrome.runtime.connectNative` to connect to native app. It will return a `chrome.runtime.Port` object. Then use `Port.postMessage` to communicate with native app.

---

Reference: [Full Documentation of Firefox WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions)